# Issue with fish-shell's command substitution

Tags: fish

I can do this in bash

```
vim `ls | percol`
```

while corresponding command in fish

```
vim (ls | percol)
```

just opened an empty file, `(ls | percol)` seemed to be ignored. what am I missing?

Comment: `doesn't work` is not very meaningful. Add output of `ls | percol` to your question.

Comment: Are you running a version of fish >= 2.6.0? If not, this is a bug in those old versions of fish and you should upgrade.

Comment: just to confirm, we are talking about this percol: https://github.com/mooz/percol

Comment: @eMBee right, https://github.com/peco/peco behaves the same way, so it's got be something with fish

Comment: @faho is right, nailed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in old fish versions that has been fixed in 2.6.0 (released June 2017).